# How to replace a string path in C#

Tags: string, c#-2.0

```
string = @"http://192.168.30.40/mylytica/Uploads/EncryptedFile/whg_12_20_2010.pdf";
if (strEncrypt.Contains("/EncryptedFile"))
{
     strEncrypt.Replace(@"/EncryptedFile", @"/DecryptedFile");
}
iFrame_pdf.Attributes.Add("src", strEncrypt);
```

it doesn't work for me:(
i need to replace the file path Encrypted into Decrypted

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

string strEncrypt = @"http://192.168.30.40/mylytica/Uploads/EncryptedFile/whg_12_20_2010.pdf";
if (strEncrypt.Contains("EncryptedFile"))
{
  strEncrypt = strEncrypt.Replace(@"EncryptedFile", @"DecryptedFile");
}

Answer (score 2):

.NET Strings are immutable, so `Replace()` returns a new String.

Do it like this:

```
string strEncrypt = @"http://192.168.30.40/mylytica/Uploads/EncryptedFile/whg_12_20_2010.pdf";    
if (strEncrypt.Contains("/EncryptedFile"))    
{    
  strEncrypt = strEncrypt.Replace(@"/EncryptedFile", @"/DecryptedFile");
}
```

Also: remember to consider what the result should be if `strEncrypt` is something like `"http://192.168.30.40/mylytica/Uploads/EncryptedFile/EncryptedFile.pdf"`.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable so you need to assign the new string to a variable:

`strEncrypt = strEncrypt.Replace(@"/EncryptedFile", @"/DecryptedFile");`

Comment: almost voted for this, except that the variable name is different :)

Comment: You didn't look close enough :)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this:

```
strEncrypt.Replace(@"/EncryptedFile", @"/DecryptedFile");
```

To this:

```
strEncrypt = strEncrypt.Replace(@"/EncryptedFile", @"/DecryptedFile");
```

From Microsoft docs on String.Replace (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx):

Note
This method does not modify the value of the current instance. Instead, it returns a new string in which all occurrences of oldValue are replaced by newValue.